# PHP - Onclick display specific table row based on matched id

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I'm currently working on an "app" for a school assignment. This "app" handles a test. So employees can login and select a client, register a client, and take a test with the client. All this has to be stored in a database.

I am at the point where the login for employees works and you can register a client. Al this is stored in a database.

Now I'm stuck at the point where the employe has the overview of the firstname and lastname of the clients in the database. The employe can click on the client and than all the information show show up next to the list of clients. Sadly I can't get this working. After a minimal of 12 hours trying searching, searching what i just searched and more searching.

**Sidenote:** *I am new to PHP and MySQL.*

I will include links to how it should be and where I am just to be as transparant as possible!

Things I have tried:

```
<?php while (mysqli_num_rows($resultId)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  if (mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM clienten_info WHERE id=$id")) {
    echo "alle informatie van die id";
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}?>
```

I tried an onclick on the  with this code:

```
<?php function checkID() {
  $resultCheck = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM clienten_info WHERE id ='$uniqueId'");
   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultCheck) == 1) {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCheck);
        $goed = "goooood";
   } else {
       $fout = "geen gegevens gevonden";
   }
}?>

<?php $resultCheck = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM clienten_info WHERE id ='$uniqueId'");
  if (mysqli_num_rows($resultCheck) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCheck);
    echo "naam:" . $row['firstname'];
  } else {
    echo "fout";
  }?>
```

And a few more.

My full source code:
https://pastebin.com/Nz1VNDxE (did pastebin because the code is long but wanted to give all code to be transparant)

Images
http://pho.to/AgdSN 
How it should be (the upper pic)

**Left clients**
**right clients information**

How it now looks (the lower pic)

As you can see the left side is filed using information from the database and when you click on one of these names you should get all the details on the right side.

Comment: `mysqli_query(` doesn't work as you are using it. You need to pass the connection object. You also are open to SQL injections. You could just hide the data on the page and have JS display it on click. I'm also not clear on what point you are failing at.

Comment: In the section where I echo the clients from the database I want to have a click function on each of them. When I, for example, click on the second client, all its information should popup. But I can't seem to fix this..

Comment: I don't know where your current issue is..are you using a form, AJAX, hiding the data in the DOM, etc.

Comment: I am usig a form, not with AJAX. I have this form showing up with jQuery css property, from display none to display block. The issue is i dont know how I can manage to retrive specific data from the database by clicking on a unique client. Sorry for my terrible explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching more i came across a form where someone posted the same thing. The solution provided to him did not work for me entirely but I did manage to get it to work.

Here is the link to the formpost: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/259091/on-click-display-only-particular-user-details

So what I did is use an iframe to load a second page. This iframe i placed where I wanted to display the user details.

The page where user data is retrieved from the database contains this code:

```
        $sqllijst         =       "SELECT id, firstname, preposition, lastname FROM clienten_info";
        $result           =       mysqli_query($connection, $sqllijst);



        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               $uniqueId = $row['id'];
               echo "<a name='$uniqueId' href='details.php?id=".$row['id']."' target='clienten-details'>" . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['preposition'] . "," . " " . $row['firstname'] . "</a>";

             }
        }

       ?>`
```

So this will give the user a link to its unique ID. The details page only contains a table and a connection to the database so that the information can be retrieved.

Also via the `$_GET` command I managed to get the specific details of that one user.

`

```
$sqldisplay = "SELECT * FROM clienten_info WHERE id=$_GET[id]";
$resultdisplay = mysqli_query($connection, $sqldisplay);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultdisplay);
```

So this block of code will connect the database. The only thing I had to do was a simple $row['yourDatabaseNames'] to display the content of the specific ID's rows.

Hope I manage to help someone with the same problem. I guess there will be more efficient ways to get the same result. If this is the case let me know, cause I really want to know!